# requested resource is not available?

Tags: grails, database-migration, grails-plugin

Even after changing a domain slightly and publishing the domain and changelog file to remote server, the following error(attached image) is shown upon accessing the dev or remote server

I changed the Race domain by adding a new property

```
String testing
```

and then added this line to changelog file

```
changeSet(author:"user (generated)", id:"1431922413415-1"){
   addColumn(tableName:"race"){
      column(name:"testing", type:"varchar(255)"){
         constraints(nullable:"false")
      }
   }
}
```

and after committing and pushing the change to remote server I get the error as attached in this email.

[image]

Comment: have you set the `updateOnStart` property in Config?

Comment: the config has, grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']

Comment: I suspect error is related to something else, have you checked the `race` table gets not updated?

Comment: you are right the race table isnt affected i.e new column testing isnt added. strange!